# Reading Tiled Images with PyLibtiff

Tags: python, tiff, tile, corrupt, libtiff

I recently downloaded and installed PyLibTIFF from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pil) and have been trying to read tiled tiff images.

I can read the scan-lined images perfectly but cant seem to even find the correct function to read tiles. I've searched through the entire libtif directory in my python site-packages folder and haven't found any kind of "read_tile" command.

I'm basically trying to transcode from [this example](http://www.libtiff.org/libtiff.html#Tiles):

```
TIFF* tif = TIFFOpen("myfile.tif", "r");
if (tif) {
uint32 imageWidth, imageLength;
uint32 tileWidth, tileLength;
uint32 x, y;
tdata_t buf;

TIFFGetField(tif, TIFFTAG_IMAGEWIDTH, &imageWidth);
TIFFGetField(tif, TIFFTAG_IMAGELENGTH, &imageLength);
TIFFGetField(tif, TIFFTAG_TILEWIDTH, &tileWidth);
TIFFGetField(tif, TIFFTAG_TILELENGTH, &tileLength);
buf = _TIFFmalloc(TIFFTileSize(tif));
for (y = 0; y < imageLength; y += tileLength)
    for (x = 0; x < imageWidth; x += tileWidth)
    TIFFReadTile(tif, buf, x, y, 0);
_TIFFfree(buf);
TIFFClose(tif);
```

to python.

So far I've gotten:

```
tif = TIFF.open(tif_path, 'r')

image_width     = tif.GetField("ImageWidth")
image_length    = tif.GetField("ImageLength")
tile_width      = tif.GetField("TileWidth")
tile_length     = tif.GetField("TileLength")

y = 0
while y < image_length:

    x = 0
    while x < image_width:

        print tif.read_tile(x, y, 0)

        x += tile_width

    y += tile_length

tif.close()
```

I actually just need to test if the tiff is corrupt or not. tif.info() doesn't help though because it just reads the file header which is offten intact even in the corrupt tifs.

Any help, thought's or ideas would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation on [libtiff's project page](http://code.google.com/p/pylibtiff/):

"""Warning: pylibtiff currently supports reading and writing images that are stored using *TIFF strips*. Patches are welcome to support tiled TIFF images."""

However, since it is a pure python package using  ctypes, and you have identified a single call that is missing, it is very well possible that you can copy and paste from other function  wrappers there to write your call to TIFFReadTile

Comment: Thanks for your reply but yeah I did see that first quoted line doing my initial searches. Could you please give an example of what you suggested though?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm confused with tiff nomenclature, as I'm used to referring to a tiff movie as a tiff *stack* as opposed to a *tiled* tiff image. I can iterate over my tiff stack with `iter_images`:

```
tif = TIFF.open('tiffimage.tif')

for image in tif.iter_images():
    *do stuff with image*
```

Or select one image from the movie by using:

```
l = list(tif.iter_images())
plt.matshow(l[100))
plt.show()
```

Perhaps the [tiffile.py](http://code.google.com/p/pylibtiff/) module by Christoph Gohlke is interesting for you as well, as referenced on the pylibtiff site. But you might be using this already as the page you link is also maintained by Gohlke?

Comment: The problem is that "iter_images" goes through a tiff's layers. The makeup of tiled tiffs is quite different so that function doesn't work. The "tiled" tiffs are a result of "mipmapping" - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mipmap which I guess isn't as common as the standard layered tiffs. Thanks for the response though.